# How do get params that have no specific names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to find how to get multiple params in react and in most of the examples the params have names like `:id` e.g

```
to="/movie/:id"
```

So to get such you just use:

```
const {id} = useParams();
```

But for my case i don't have specific names. How to i get these params?

```
//res is an object
<Link to={`/movie/${res.id}/${res.link_id}`}>
```

Comment: If you want to experiment, remove the destructing from around id and just assign the useParams result to a variable. Then log that to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. I confused `<Route>` with `<Link>`

In the `<Link>` tag i don't need to define the params. It is the `<Route>`  tag that the params are already defined i.e

```
<Route path='/movie/:movieId/:linkId' element={<Movie />} />

//Then in link tag is just an like an <a> tag
<Link to={`/movie/${res.id}/${res.link_id}`}>
```

Then in my component I just get them as

```
const {movieId,linkId} = useParams()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the component in the Link props:
Suppose that your new Component is named MovieDetails.

```
const MovieDetails=()=>{
    const {id} = useParams();
}
```

Link Component:

```
<Link to={`/movie/${res.id}/${res.link_id}`} component={MovieDetails}>
```